# Getting a common column value over a group

Tags: sql

I have table like below:

```
id  req
1   a
1   b
2   a
2   c
3   a
4   d
```

So value 'a' in req column is common accoros ids 1,2,3. How can I achieve that?

Comment: id req
1 a
1 b
2 a
2 c
3 a
4 d

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Which dbms do you use? Add sample data and expected result to your question

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: Expected result is value 'a', because it is common across all ids.

Comment: Not common across all id's. ID 4 doesn't contain 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

Here it will give you which ID's are mapped with which req

```
CREATE TABLE #test (id int,  req varchar(1))

INSERT INTO #test VALUES
(1,   'a'),
(1,   'b'),
(2,   'a'),
(2,  'c'),
(3,   'a'),
(4,   'd')

SELECT req
    ,abc = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ID)
            FROM #test t2
            WHERE t2.req = t1.req
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
FROM #test t1
GROUP BY req

DROP TABLE #test
```

The output is as follows:-

```
req abc
a   1,2,3
b   1
c   2
d   4
```